# gulp build failing with cryptic ENOENT

Tags: gulp, reactjs

I've recently started learning react and I'm getting this cryptic exception on a gulp build.

This project was originally created with the react-reflux generator

```
[18:35:03] gulp-rev-all: Finding references in [ /404.html ]
[18:35:03] gulp-rev-all: Not renaming [ /404.html ] due to filter rules.
[18:35:03] gulp-rev-all: Finding references in [ /styles/main.css ]

events.js:72
        throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
              ^
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory '{/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/.tmp/react.js,/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/app/react.js}'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:439:18)
    at Object.fs.readFileSync (fs.js:290:15)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/node_modules/gulp-useref/index.js:81:61)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/node_modules/gulp-useref/index.js:70:35)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at DestroyableTransform.<anonymous> (/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/node_modules/gulp-useref/index.js:46:36)
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at DestroyableTransform._transform (/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/node_modules/gulp-useref/index.js:43:15)
    at DestroyableTransform.Transform._read (/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/node_modules/gulp-useref/node_modules/through2/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_transform.js:184:10)
```

My gulp file is like so

```
var gulp        = require('gulp');

var $           = require('gulp-load-plugins')();
var del         = require('del');
var source      = require('vinyl-source-stream');
var browserify  = require('browserify');
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var less        = require('gulp-less');

var env = 'dev';

gulp.task('clean:dev', function() {
  return del(['.tmp']);
});

gulp.task('clean:dist', function() {
  return del(['dist']);
});

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  var bundler = browserify('./app/scripts/app.js', {
    extensions: ['.jsx'],
    debug: env == 'dev'
  }).transform('reactify');

  return bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'));
});


gulp.task('imagemin', function() {
  return gulp.src('app/images/*')
    .pipe($.imagemin({
            progressive: true,
            svgoPlugins: [{removeViewBox: false}]
    }))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/images'));
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
  return gulp.src(['app/*.txt', 'app/*.ico'])
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})

gulp.task('bundle', function () {
  var assets = $.useref.assets({searchPath: '{.tmp,app}'});
  var jsFilter = $.filter(['**/*.js']);
  var cssFilter = $.filter(['**/*.css']);
  var htmlFilter = $.filter(['**/*.html']);
  var lessFilter = $.filter(['**/*.less']);

  return gulp.src('app/*.html')
    .pipe(assets)
    .pipe(assets.restore())
    .pipe($.useref())
    .pipe(jsFilter)
    .pipe($.uglify())
    .pipe(jsFilter.restore())
    .pipe(cssFilter)
    .pipe($.autoprefixer({
      browsers: ['last 5 versions']
    }))
    .pipe($.minifyCss())
    .pipe(cssFilter.restore())
    .pipe(lessFilter)
    .pipe(less())
    .pipe(lessFilter.restore())
    .pipe(htmlFilter)
    .pipe($.htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true}))
    .pipe(htmlFilter.restore())
    .pipe($.revAll({ ignore: [/^\/favicon.ico$/g, '.html'] }))
    .pipe($.revReplace())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
    .pipe($.size());
});

gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  return gulp.src(['.tmp', 'app'])
    .pipe($.webserver({
      host: '0.0.0.0', //change to 'localhost' to disable outside connections
      livereload: true,
      open: true
    }));
});

gulp.task('serve', function() {
  runSequence('clean:dev', ['scripts'], 'webserver');

  gulp.watch('app/*.html');

  gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.js', ['scripts']);

  gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.jsx', ['scripts']);

  gulp.watch('app/scripts/**/*.less', ['scripts']);

});

gulp.task('build', function() {
  env = 'prod';

  runSequence(['clean:dev', 'clean:dist'],
              ['scripts', 'imagemin', 'copy'],
              'bundle');
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you `npm install react`?

Comment: yes, I did install react

Comment: Okay then you need to go through all of your imports because Gulp can't find React in it's expected path `/Users/Shared/java/projects/react/msa/react-project/.tmp/react.js`.

Comment: I'm wondering if I'm correctly referencing it from my js/jsx files. I use require('react') and require('react/addons'). Shit, as I'm typing this, I realize i didn't install react-addons. Hmm, installing it didn't help. Same error. I'm also wondering about this tmp directory. I sort of blindly accepted it in the generated gulpfile. But I'm not sure about its purpose, a temporary transpile directory?

Comment: `require('react/addons')` resolves to node_modules/react/addons.js, so that's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the error it shows:

```
Error: ENOENT, no such file or directory 
'{/.../react-project/.tmp/react.js,/...react-project/app/react.js}'
```

This `{path,otherpath}` syntax means it's looking for the file at either of the locations.

The webserver task tells it to look in these directories for assets to serve:

```
gulp.task('webserver', function() {
  return gulp.src(['.tmp', 'app'])
    .pipe($.webserver({
```

So the problem isn't actually in the build, it's because something's making a http request for react.js.  Look in .tmp/index.html or app/index.html, and remove the script tag with react.js in the src.  It's included in the bundle, and doesn't need to be loaded manually.  Ensure there's a script tag like this:

```
<script src="/scripts/app.js"></script>
</body>
```

This is the path because the webserver serves from .tmp and we output the bundle to .tmp/scripts and name it app.js with these lines:

```
  return bundler.bundle()
    .pipe(source('app.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('.tmp/scripts'));
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, the setup is already as you describe

Comment: Try running `gulp scripts`, `gulp bundle`, `gulp webserver`.  Which one gives you the error?

Comment: Do you see the tasks that are in the build task (bottom of the script)?  Run each of those individually.  You still don't know which task is the problem...

Comment: sorry, I mis typed. gulp bundle gives the exception. Given the exception, I assume it's .pipe($.useref()). If I escape everything below it until, gulp.dest('dist'), it gives this exception, so this should be it

Comment: Shit, I do have a reference to react.js in the index.html. I was referencing the wrong file in another project when I checked.